# Closest match in text fields between two tables: how to improve plpgsql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to geocode data in one table (A) with address data contained in another table (B). As street names can be written differently, I would like to first go through the data in A and for each tuple find the street name in B that is closest to the one in the tuple of A, within a given postcode zone. For text matching I am currently using the similarity() function and the '%' operator from the pg_trgm extension.

A contains data from different countries and so the function parameters contain the respective tables names, but also the country I'm treating and the names of the relevant fields in the address data table (B).

Relevant fields in the respective tables are:

A

```
id            | bigint                | non NULL
cp            | character varying     |
rue           | character varying     | 
rue_trouvee   | character varying     | 
iso_pays      | character varying     |
```

with index:

```
"tableA_temp_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"idx_tableA_pays" btree (iso_pays)
```

B

```
rue              | character varying(90) | 
code_post        | character varying(5)  | 
x                | double precision      | 
y                | double precision      |
```

with indexes:

```
"idx_fradresses_code_post" btree (code_post)
"idx_fradresses_rue_trgm" gin (rue gin_trgm_ops)
```

Currently, I am using this PLPGSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trouver_rue_proche(datatable TEXT, addresstable TEXT, address_rue TEXT, address_cp TEXT, pays TEXT) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE

rec_data RECORD;
nom_rue RECORD;

counter INTEGER;

BEGIN

    counter := 0; 

    FOR rec_data IN
       EXECUTE SELECT id, rue, cp FROM ' || quote_ident(datatable) || ' WHERE iso_pays = ' || quote_literal(pays) || ' AND x is null'
   LOOP

       counter := counter + 1;
       EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || quote_ident(address_rue) || ' as rue_t FROM geocode.' ||   quote_ident(addresstable) || ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(address_cp) || ' = ' || quote_literal(rec_data.cp) || ' AND ' || quote_ident(address_rue) || ' % ' || quote_literal(rec_data.rue) || ' ORDER BY similarity(' || quote_ident(address_rue) || ', ' || quote_literal(rec_data.rue) || ') DESC LIMIT 1' INTO nom_rue;
       EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || quote_ident(datatable) || ' SET rue_trouvee = $1 WHERE id = $2' USING nom_rue.rue_t, rec_data.id;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN counter;

END

$$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When trying to run this function for a country where 584,670 tuples still have x=NULL, and for which the address table contains 25,228,340 tuples, the function has been running for almost 3 days now.

My machine has the following specs:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3225 CPU @ 3.30GHz
8GB RAM
```

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.1 with the following parameters in postgresql.conf:

```
shared_buffers = 4096MB
work_mem = 512MB
```

Any hints on how to improve the efficiency of this function ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't write this as one query rather than looping?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Thanks for the hint, I decided to post the query I used as an answer to be able to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the hint from Richard Huxton, this is the query I used:

```
UPDATE tableA set rue_trouvee=t4.rue 
   FROM (SELECT id, rue 
       FROM (SELECT t1.id, t2.rue, similarity(t1.rue, t2.rue) as similarity, rank() 
             OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY similarity(t1.rue, t2.rue) DESC) 
             FROM tableA t1 JOIN tableB t2 
             ON (t1.cp = t2.code_post AND t1.rue % t2.rue) 
             WHERE t1.x is null AND t1.iso_pays='FR') t3 
       WHERE rank=1) t4 
   WHERE tableA.id=t4.id
```

I imagine that this could be solved more elegantly and more efficiently, but at least this worked and gave me the updates I wanted after 5 hours.

Comment: Cool. There's always a point at which spending more time improving efficiency stops being worth it. I think you can accept your own answer, btw.